# Getting Error on Dialog Cancel

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Here is my code, I am creating a dialog to ask the user to send application to background on cancel. I am getting this error:

> 11-26 14:12:01.197: E/ViewRootImpl(5472): sendUserActionEvent() mView
>   == null

```
    mbtnimglogout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

         @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            closeapp();
            }});
}
void closeapp()
{
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
    .setTitle("Closing Dealer Form")
    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to send Application to Background?")
    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

   moveTaskToBack(true);
    //    finish();    
    }

})
.setNegativeButton("No", null)
.show();
}
```

Comment: please add your full logcat error with the code of your `moveTaskToBack` method code.

Comment: Try out with `alertDialog.setNeutralButton("OK", null);`

Comment: here is logcat error 11-26 14:38:13.911: E/ViewRootImpl(8871): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null

Answer (score 0):

```
.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
{
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
   dialog.cancel();
}}).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You must set the Listener for Cancel Option:

```
.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, just close
                        // the dialog box and do nothing
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
```

For Reference follow this Tutorial[Here](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-alert-dialog-example/)